# How to implement selectable boxes exact same as google maps filter options shown in below image. Also add any number of options programmatcially

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-layout, checkbox, radio-button

[image]

I am trying to implement list of multiple pincode suggestions in a similar fashion as the filter options shown in above image(Relevance, Open now, Top-rated, Visited, ...).
Now here 7 options are provided in google maps which are fixed but I'll only be able to set pincode suggestions based on users current location & number of suggestion will vary, so a way to dynamically add these items is required.
Here In the Image we can select any number of suggestions & I also want the same for my implementation. Similarly this should be horizontally scrollable single strip.

I am not aware of the technical term for these but I've seen it in many popular apps. Still, I have not been able to find anything similar in android documentation, material UI and stackoverflow. So if it's something popular or standard then please point me into right direction.

What I've tried: Radio Groups/Buttons, Customizable Checkbox, Horizontal Scroll without scroll bar & similar other stuff but no luck.

Thanks a lot in advance for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Those are called `Chip` in Flutter.
Here's how you can achieve a horizontal scrolling strip with check/uncheck behavior (in a `StatefulWidget`'s `State` class) :

```
Map<String, bool> filters = {
  "Relevance": true, 
  "Open now": false, 
  "Top": false,
  "Something": true,
  "Another thing": false,
  "Many filters": false,
};
    
// In build()
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: filters.entries.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => setState(() => filters[filters.keys.elementAt(index)] = !filters.values.elementAt(index)),
    child: Chip(
      backgroundColor: filters.values.elementAt(index) ? Colors.white : Colors.grey,
      label: Text(filters.keys.elementAt(index))),
  );
})
```

You could also extract the `filters` map in a separate "business logic" class with a [state management solution](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro).